# How do we solve the exact recurrence for $T(1) = 1, T(n) = 3T(n - 1) + 2n + 2$ for $n > 1$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

This looks like an exponential recurrence due to the 3 behind $T$, but I'm not sure how to formally solve for $T(n)$ without $T$ on the righthand side.

Comment: do not sweat: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%281%29%3D1%2C+t%28n%29%3D3t%28n-1%29%2B2+n%2B2 ]

Answer (score 4):

> **Hint** $$T(n)+n=3(T(n-1)+(n-1))+5$$

So we just solve $a_1=2$, $a_{n}=3a_{n-1}+5$.

> **Hint** $$a_n+\frac{5}{2}=3(a_{n-1}+\frac{5}{2})$$

Then $b_1=\frac{9}{2}$ and $b_n=3b_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
T(n)=A(n) 3^{n-1}
$$
substituting
$$
A(n+1) 3^n = 3 A(n) 3^{n-1}+ 2n + 2$$
Hence
$$
A(n+1) = A(n) + \frac{2( n + 1)}{3^n}$$

Hence $$
A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{3^{k-1}}
$$
Finally
$$
T(n) = 3^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac {k}{3^{k-1}}$$

There are some tricks to simplify the last summation.